# Assert css colour for pseudo code

Tags: java, css, eclipse, selenium

For a website I have to assert the use of colours. The element is easy to find but I can't seem to figure out how to assert the color as the css uses psuedo code to generate the displayed color. I use the following to get to the element and retreive the color:

```
assertEquals("rgba(236, 117, 4 , 1)", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ab-toggle']")).getCssValue("color"));
```

The code on the page is:

```
<div class="ab-toggle">::before</div> //in chrome
<div class="ab-toggle"></div> //in firebug
```

The css:

```
.contenthere .ab-toggle::before {
color: #ec7504;
content: "▾";
display: inline-block;
font-family: "icons";
font-size: 1.6em;
line-height: 1;
margin-left: 0.3em;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If I run my code it returns a comparisonFailure:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[rgba(236, 117, 4 , 1)]> but was:<[rgba(34, 34, 34, 1)]>
```

I can see this colour in the CSS too but don't know how to go about getting the correct color from the assert statement

```
 .contenthere a.expandable-toggle {
color: #222;
cursor: pointer;
```

I also tried to get to the element using a css selector instead of xpath, when I use the following:

```
assertEquals("rgba(236, 117, 4 , 1)", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.ab-toggle ::before")).getCssValue("color"));
```

it results in a NoSuchElementException. And when I try:

```
assertEquals("rgba(236, 117, 4 , 1)", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.ab-toggle")).getCssValue("color"));
```

it simply returns the old result, same as when I use xpath to locate the element

Comment: It seems you target `.ab-toggle` with your selector, but are expecting to get the color of the pseudo element `ab-toggle::after`.

Comment: I see in your edit that you wrote `"div.ab-toggle ::before"` it is mandatory to not have a white space in the selector here. Try it like this: `"div.ab-toggle::before"`.

Comment: Without the white space it still results in a NoSuchElementException: assertEquals("rgba(236, 117, 4 , 1)", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.ab-toggle::before")).getCssValue("color"));

Comment: If [this source](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/selenium/selenium.selenium.html) is correct, it seem selenium can't select pesudo elements:  >>Currently the css selector locator supports all css1, css2 and css3 selectors **except** namespace in css3, some pseudo classes(:nth-of-type, :nth-last-of-type, :first-of-type, :last-of-type, :only-of-type, :visited, :hover, :active, :focus, :indeterminate) and pseudo elements(::first-line, ::first-letter, ::selection, **::before**, **::after**).<<

Comment: Thank you Nico, it seems that I won't be able to select the pseudo element then. This check will just have to stay manual then. Can you add this as an answer, so I can accept it?